# Como modificar una linea de texto de un archivo en java

Tags: java, lista, eclipse

Hola amigos buenas tardes, estoy metiendo una validación en proceso batch hecho en java por lo cual el aplicativo lee un archivo txt, lo de la lectura si lo hace bien, anexo un ejemplo:

```
1203870|0|0|1203870|2220527|P|R09|5555555555|4ab7a940-50fc-49af-9555-90116ed11203|24|1|1041.68|1041.92|0.24|2220531|TF|59009950|0|352826110083252|469457577|TC|65969997|4|FULANO DE TAL|TEZJ720920KV8|BNMEX|102|152605399201203870|N|2220531
1203872|0|0|1203872|2220527|P|R09|5555555555|029e9e18-1423-42da-a7ba-c3cf83794b91|24|1|558.09|558.33|0.24|2220531|TF|58989814|0|358779103355928|469553357|TC|66020182|4|FULANO DE TAL|MAOE610214PJ2|PROSA|102|152605399201203872|N|2220531
1224961|0|0|1224961|2220527|P|R09|5555555555|a776c830-5af8-4a59-9d31-58ad119c9c6e|24|1|76.24|76.48|0.24|2220531|TF|58700631|0|861358043346345|469457344|TC|65969927|4|FULANO DE TAL|MATA761026MT0|BNMEX|102|152475399201224961|N|2220531
1329072|0|0|1329072|2220527|P|R09|5555555555|d7295ac6-f68e-40be-9635-6c65a44cc2b6|24|1|1041.63|1041.87|0.24|2220531|TF|58929920|0|353839107639563|469440247|TC|65977059|4|FULANO DE TAL|PAAE670610CH6|BNMEX|102|195455399201329072|N|2220531
```

Lo que requiero hacer es que si en caso de que encuentre 0.24 este numero se convierta en 0.00 y tomando de ejemplo uno de los registros que tiene los números 1041.68 y 1041.92 entonces el 1041.68 se elimine y tome el siguiente numero 1041.92, es decir, que quede así:

```
1203870|0|0|1203870|2220527|P|R09|5554572125|4ab7a940-50fc-49af-9555-90116ed11203|24|1|1041.92|1041.92|0.00|2220531|TF|59009950|0|352826110083252|469457577|TC|65969997|4|JESUS ANTONIO TELLEZ ZETINA|TEZJ720920KV8|BNMEX|102|152605399201203870|N|2220531
```

y asi sucesivamente en los demas registros, para toda la lectura se encuentra este metodo java:

```
public static List<LayoutCPBES> validaReporte(List<LayoutCPBES> lstPagos, String nombreReporte, String correos, int limiteErrores, Map<Integer, String> mapDir){
        ArrayList<String> detalleErrores = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> lineasErrores = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (LayoutCPBES cPago : lstPagos) {
            String linea = "";

Metí esta validación y si está funcionando pero al ejecutarse el proceso este no funciona, ya que al terminar generar un nuevo archivo:
        
            if(cPago.getListDocumentoRelacionado().getSaldoInsoluto()==0.24) {
                LOG.info("Si entré a la validación oJO 0.24!!!!!"); //JJ
                cPago.getListDocumentoRelacionado().setSaldoInsoluto(0.00);
                
            }
            
            
            
            linea += cPago.getListDocumentoRelacionado().getCtaQueFactura() <= 0 ? "\n- La cuenta que factura no se informo" : "";
//          VALIDA NUMERO DE DIGITOS DE CUENTA
            linea += Long.toString(cPago.getListDocumentoRelacionado().getCtaQueFactura()).length() > 10 ? "\n- La cuenta que factura sobre pasa los digitos establecidos" : "";
            linea += cPago.getListDocumentoRelacionado().getFechaCorte().isEmpty() ? "\n- La fecha de corte no se informo" : "";
//          VALIDA NUMERO DE CARACTERES DE FECHA
            linea += cPago.getListDocumentoRelacionado().getFechaCorte().length() > 7 ? "\n- La fecha de corte sobre pasa el limite de caracteres" : "";
            linea += cPago.getListDocumentoRelacionado().getTipoDocumento().isEmpty() ? "\n- El tipo de documento no se informo" : "";
//          VALIDA EL TIPO DE DOCUMENTO
            linea += !validaTipoDocumento(cPago.getListDocumentoRelacionado().getTipoDocumento()) ? "\n- El tipo de documento no esta identificado, debe ser financiamiento (P) o servicio de telecomunicaciones (F)" : "";
            linea += cPago.getListDocumentoRelacionado().getRegion().isEmpty() ? "\n- La región no se informo" : "";
//          VALIDACION REGION
            linea += !validaRegion(cPago.getListDocumentoRelacionado().getRegion()) ? "\n- La region no esta identificada, debe ser R01, R02, ... o R09" : "";
            if (cPago.getListDocumentoRelacionado().getTipoDocumento().equalsIgnoreCase(Constantes.FINANCIAMIENTO)) {
                linea += cPago.getListDocumentoRelacionado().getNumTelefono() <= 0 ? "\n- El número de telefono debe ser informado en financiamientos" : "";
                linea += cPago.getListDocumentoRelacionado().getUuidRelacionado().isEmpty() ? "\n- El uuid debe ser informado en financiamientos" : "";
//              VALIDA NUMERO DE CARACTERES DE UUID
                linea += cPago.getListDocumentoRelacionado().getUuidRelacionado().length() > 36 ? "\n- El uuid sobre pasa el limite de caracteres" : "";
                linea += cPago.getListDocumentoRelacionado().getSeqNumFineq() <= 0 ? "\n- La secuencia fineq debe ser informada en financiamientos" : "";
                linea += cPago.getListDocumentoRelacionado().getImeiFineq().isEmpty() ? "\n- El imei debe ser informado en financiamientos" : "";
            }
            linea += cPago.getListDocumentoRelacionado().getNumParcialidad() <= 0 ? "\n- El número de parcialidad no se informo" : "";
            
        
//          VALIDACION DE MONTOS
            linea += cPago.getListDocumentoRelacionado().getSaldoAnterior() <= 0 ? "\n- El saldo anterior no puede ser un valor negativo o igual a 0" : "";
            linea += cPago.getListDocumentoRelacionado().getImporte() <= 0 ? "\n- El importe no puede ser un valor negativo o igual a 0" : "";
            linea += cPago.getListDocumentoRelacionado().getSaldoInsoluto() < 0 ? "\n- El saldo insoluto no puede ser un valor negativo" : "";
            
//          SE VALIDA SI EL SALDO INSOLUTO ES 0.24

//          if(cPago.getListDocumentoRelacionado().getSaldoInsoluto()==0.24) {
//              LOG.info("Si entré a la validación oJO 0.24!!!!!"); //JJ
//              cPago.getListDocumentoRelacionado().setSaldoInsoluto(0.00);
//                      
//              
//              
//          }
            
            
//          SE VALIDA SI EL IMPORTE PAGADO ES MAYOR AL SALDO ANTERIOR
            Double montoPagado = (double)0, montoAnterior = (double)0;
            montoPagado = cPago.getListDocumentoRelacionado().getImporte();
            montoPagado = Math.round(montoPagado*100d)/100d;
            montoAnterior = cPago.getListDocumentoRelacionado().getSaldoAnterior();
            montoAnterior = Math.round(montoAnterior*100d)/100d;

            linea += Double.compare(montoPagado, montoAnterior) > 0 ? "\n- El importe pagado no puede ser mayor al saldo anterior" : "";//Se pinta JJ

//          SE VALIDA SI EL SALDO ANTERIOR - EL IMPORTE ES = AL SALDO INSOLUTO
            Double montoInsoluto = (double)0, saldoInsoluto = (double)0;
            montoInsoluto = montoAnterior - montoPagado;
            montoInsoluto = Math.round(montoInsoluto*100d)/100d;
            saldoInsoluto = cPago.getListDocumentoRelacionado().getSaldoInsoluto();
            saldoInsoluto = Math.round(saldoInsoluto*100d)/100d;
            
//          if(saldoInsoluto ==0.24) {
//              LOG.info("Si entré a la validación oJO 0.24 66666666!!!!!");
//              //montoPagado=montoAnterior;
//              saldoInsoluto=0.00;
//              
//          }
//          
//          if(cPago.getListDocumentoRelacionado().getSaldoInsoluto()==0.24) {
//              LOG.info("Si entré a la validación oJO 0.24!!!!!"); //JJ
//              cPago.getListDocumentoRelacionado().setSaldoInsoluto(0.00);
//              //cPago.getListDocumentoRelacionado().setSaldoInsoluto(0.00);   
//              
//              
//          }

            linea += Double.compare(montoInsoluto, saldoInsoluto) != 0 ? "\n- El saldo insoluto no cuadra con el importe pagado al saldo anterior" : "";//Se pinta JJ
            linea += cPago.getListDocumentoRelacionado().getFechaPago().isEmpty() ? "\n- La fecha de pago no se informo" : "";
            

            
//          VALIDA NUMERO DE CARACTERES DE FECHA
            linea += cPago.getListDocumentoRelacionado().getFechaPago().length() > 7 ? "\n- La fecha de pago sobre pasa el limite de caracteres" : "";
            linea += cPago.getListDocumentoRelacionado().getSerie().isEmpty() ? "\n- La serie no se informo" : "";
//          VALIDA SERIE
            linea += cPago.getListDocumentoRelacionado().getSerie().length() > 2 ? "\n- La serie sobre pasa el limite de caracteres" : "";
            linea += cPago.getListDocumentoRelacionado().getFolio() <= 0 ? "\n- El folio no se informo" : "";
//          VALIDA FOLIO
            linea += Long.toString(cPago.getListDocumentoRelacionado().getFolio()).length() > 18 ? "\n- El folio sobre pasa el limite de digitos" : "";
//          VALIDA NUMERO LOTE PAGO
            linea += cPago.getListDocumentoRelacionado().getNumLotePago() < 0 ? "\n- El número de lote de pago no se informo" : "";
            linea += !isNumeric(String.valueOf(cPago.getListDocumentoRelacionado().getNumLotePago())) ? "\n- El número de lote de pago debe ser numerico" : "";
            linea += soloLetras(String.valueOf(cPago.getListDocumentoRelacionado().getNumLotePago())) ? "\n- El número de lote de pago no debe contener letras" : "";
            linea += cPago.getListDocumentoRelacionado().getTipoLotePago().isEmpty() ? "\n- El tipo de lote de pago no se informo" : "";
//          VALIDA TIPO LOTE PAGO
            linea += isNumeric(cPago.getListDocumentoRelacionado().getTipoLotePago()) ? "\n- El tipo de lote de pago no debe ser numerico" : "";
            linea += !soloLetras(cPago.getListDocumentoRelacionado().getTipoLotePago()) ? "\n- El tipo de lote de pago contiene caracteres no permitidos" : "";
            linea += cPago.getListDocumentoRelacionado().getTipoLotePago().length() > 2 ? "\n- El tipo de lote de pago sobre pasa el limite de caracteres" : "";
//          VALIDA SECUENCIA LOTE PAGO
            linea += cPago.getListDocumentoRelacionado().getSecuenciaLotePago() < 0 ? "\n- La secuencia del lote de pago no se informo" : "";
            linea += !isNumeric(String.valueOf(cPago.getListDocumentoRelacionado().getSecuenciaLotePago())) ? "\n- La secuencia del lote de pago debe ser numerico" : "";
            linea += soloLetras(String.valueOf(cPago.getListDocumentoRelacionado().getSecuenciaLotePago())) ? "\n- La secuencia del lote de pago no debe contener letras" : "";
//          VALIDA EL METODO DE PAGO
            linea += cPago.getListDocumentoRelacionado().getMetodoPagoM2k().isEmpty() ? "\n- El método de pago no se informo" : "";
            linea += cPago.getListDocumentoRelacionado().getMetodoPagoM2k().length() > 2 ? "\n- El método de pago sobre pasa el limite de digitos" : "";
            linea += !isNumeric(cPago.getListDocumentoRelacionado().getMetodoPagoM2k()) ? "\n- El método de pago debe ser numerico" : "";
            linea += soloLetras(cPago.getListDocumentoRelacionado().getMetodoPagoM2k()) ? "\n- El método de pago no debe contener letras" : "";
            linea += cPago.getListDocumentoRelacionado().getNombreCliente().isEmpty() ? "\n- El nombre del cliente no se informo" : "";
//          VALIDA NOMBRE CLIENTE
            linea += cPago.getListDocumentoRelacionado().getNombreCliente().length() > 132 ? "\n- El nombre del cliente sobre pasa el limite de caracteres" : "";
            linea += cPago.getListDocumentoRelacionado().getRfcReceptor().isEmpty() ? "\n- El rfc del cliente no se informo" : "";
//          VALIDA RFC CLIENTE
            linea += cPago.getListDocumentoRelacionado().getRfcReceptor().length() > 15 ? "\n- El rfc del cliente sobre pasa el limite de caracteres" : "";
            linea += cPago.getListDocumentoRelacionado().getOrigenPago().length() > 5 ? "\n- El origen de pago sobre pasa el limite de caracteres" : "";
            linea += cPago.getListDocumentoRelacionado().getUsuarioPago().length() > 20 ? "\n- El usuario de pago sobre pasa el limite de caracteres" : "";
            linea += cPago.getListDocumentoRelacionado().getAcctId().isEmpty() ? "\n- El aactid no se informo" : "";
//          VALIDA AACTID
            linea += cPago.getListDocumentoRelacionado().getAcctId().length() > 20 ? "\n- El aactid sobre pasa el limite de caracteres" : "";
            linea += cPago.getListDocumentoRelacionado().getEstatusPago().isEmpty() ? "\n- Se debe informar el estatus del pago (N, S, R)" : "";
//          VALIDA ESTATUS PAGO
            linea += !validaTipoPago(cPago.getListDocumentoRelacionado().getEstatusPago()) ? "\n- El estatus de pago no se tiene identificado debe ser N, S o R" : "";
            linea += cPago.getListDocumentoRelacionado().getFechaCreacionBES().isEmpty() ? "\n- La fecha de creación en BES no se informo" : "";
//          VALIDA FECHA BES
            linea += cPago.getListDocumentoRelacionado().getFechaCreacionBES().length() > 7 ? "\n- La fecha de creación BES sobre pasa el limite de caracteres" : "";
            if (linea.isEmpty() || linea.equals("")) {
                cPago.getListDocumentoRelacionado().setInconsisDatos(Constantes.NO);
                if (cPago.getListDocumentoRelacionado().getTipoDocumento()
                        .equalsIgnoreCase(Constantes.FINANCIAMIENTO)) {
                    cPago.getListDocumentoRelacionado().setIndGenCp(Constantes.SI);
                }
            } else {
                cPago.getListDocumentoRelacionado().setInconsisDatos(Constantes.SI);
                lineasErrores.add("\n# Linea ["+cPago.getListDocumentoRelacionado().getNumLinea()+"] Cuenta -->> "+cPago.getListDocumentoRelacionado().getCtaQueFactura()+"\n{"+cPago.getListDocumentoRelacionado().toString()+"}");
                detalleErrores.add("\n# Linea :: [ "+cPago.getListDocumentoRelacionado().getNumLinea()+"] Cuenta -->> "+cPago.getListDocumentoRelacionado().getCtaQueFactura()+linea);
            }
        }
        String mensaje = "";
        if (detalleErrores != null && detalleErrores.size() > 0 && detalleErrores.size() <= limiteErrores) {
            LOG.info("[TBVRB] Se encontraron " + detalleErrores.size() +" inconsistencias en el reporte " + nombreReporte);
            mensaje="EL REPORTE "+nombreReporte+" PRESENTA INCONSISTENCIAS EN LAS SIGUIENTES LINEAS: ";
            for (int i = 0; i < lineasErrores.size(); i++) {
                mensaje +="\n"+lineasErrores.get(i);
            }
            mensaje += "\n\n DETALLE DE ERRORES POR LINEA: ";
            for (int i = 0; i < detalleErrores.size(); i++) {
                mensaje +="\n"+detalleErrores.get(i);
            }
            mensaje += "\n\nSE GENERO REPORTE CON LOS REGISTROS QUE PRESENTARON INCONSISTENCIAS EN LA RUTA: "+ mapDir.get(5);
            mensaje += "\n\nLA NOMENCLATURA DEL REPORTE ES: "+nombreReporte.replace(".txt", "")+"_I_YYYYMMDD_HHMMSS.txt ";
            mensaje += "\n\n\n\n +FAVOR DE REVISAR LO REPORTADO";
            Email.prepararMail("CPAGOBES - Inconsistencias encontradas en reporte "+nombreReporte, mensaje, correos);
        }else if (detalleErrores != null && detalleErrores.size() > limiteErrores) {
            LOG.info("[TBVRB] Se sobre paso el limite de inconsistencias en el reporte " + nombreReporte+" se encontraron "+detalleErrores.size()+" errores");
            mensaje = "EL REPORTE "+nombreReporte+" SOBRE PASO EL LIMITE DE INCONSISTENCIAS... \n";
            mensaje += "\nSE MOVIO EL REPORTE A LA CARPETA ERRORES: "+mapDir.get(6);
            mensaje += "\n\n\n\n +FAVOR DE REVISAR LO REPORTADO";
            Email.prepararMail("CPAGOBES - Se sobre paso el limite de inconsistencias en reporte "+nombreReporte, mensaje, correos);
            return null;
        }else {
            LOG.info("[TBVRB] No se encontraron inconsistencias en el reporte " + nombreReporte);
        }
        lstPagos = validaLotes(lstPagos);
        return lstPagos;
        
    }
```

Hay alguna otra manera de que se pueda realizar esa modificación? Espero y me puedan ayudar por favor, si hay algo que no se da a entender con gusto lo aclararé, de antemano gracias y quedo al pendiente de alguna duda o comentarios.

Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

está es la solución que yo encontré para modificar líneas de texto con Java, si bien es cierto  que la mejor forma, sería crear un objeto con todos los datos necesarios y poder realizar las modificaciones a través de sus getters y setters y a través de las clases  **ObjectInputStream** y  **ObjectOutputStream**  modificar los datos del fichero de texto. Para así evitar posibles errores con las comprobaciones del tipo String.

La solución que encontré sería:

```
package main;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Fichero original y el fichero donde renombrará los nuevos cambios.
        File ficheroEntrada = new File("fichero.txt");
        File ficheroSalida = new File("ficheroNuevo.txt");
        // Lectura y escritura de datos
        BufferedReader lector;
        BufferedWriter escritor;
        // String que almacenará cada línea para operar sobre ella. 
        String linea;
        try {
            // inicializar los Buffered con los ficheros de escritura y lectura.
            escritor = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(ficheroSalida));
            lector = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(ficheroEntrada));
            
            while ((linea = lector.readLine()) != null) {
                if (linea.contains("0.24")) {
                    // Sustitución de la línea que contiene 0.24 por los valores que deseemos. 
                    String lineaNueva = linea.replace(linea.substring(linea.indexOf("FULANO")),
                            "MENGANO " + linea.substring(linea.indexOf("DE TAL")));
                    // añadimos en el fichero nuevo, la línea modificada.
                    escritor.append(lineaNueva + " \n");

                } else {
                    // en caso de que no tuviera 0.24, también añadimos la línea. 
                    escritor.append(linea + " \n");
                }
            }
            
            // cierre de los buffered.
            escritor.close();
            lector.close();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe) {
            System.out.println("Fichero no encontrado");
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            // ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
        // borrado del fichero original.
        ficheroEntrada.delete();
        // sustitución del fichero nuevo por el nombre del original. 
        ficheroSalida.renameTo(ficheroEntrada);
    }
}
```

Espero que te sirva de guía.

Comment: Hola @aseron1988 muchas gracias por tu respuesta, lo voy a revisar y trataré de aducuarlo a mi requerimiento :)